# What is the right configuration of postfix?

Tags: postfix, email-server

How can I configure my postfix server to accept mail from pippo@postfixtest.org? I set main.cf file this way:

```
myhostname = andrea-VirtualBox
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
#/etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname postfixtest.org localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mydomain = postfixtest.org
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mail_spool_directory = /var/mail
home_mailbox = Maildir/
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = 127.0.0.1
default_transport = smtp
relay_transport = smtp
virtual_alias_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/virtual
inet_protocols = all
```

But I cannot receive on pippo@postfixtest.org emails, it seems this address doesn't exist. I've reported only lines edited by me, other configuration parameters are set to default value or are commented.

Comment: What's in `/etc/postfix/virtual` ?

Comment: there is only the following line:`pippo@postfixtest.org andrea-VirtualBox`

Comment: Is `andrea-Virtualbox` a user, or a transport?

Comment: it is the hostname of my machine

Comment: andrea or root are users on my machine, should I write it into virtual instead of andrea-VirtualBox?

Comment: That's not how virtual works in postfix, you should put a local user..

Comment: in fact I suspected that was the problem, how it works? I'm new to it and I'm not understanding so much how to receive email on postfix server, I mean on what addresses...

Comment: Also, remember to run `postmap /etc/postfix/virtual`

Comment: There's not enough space here to explain the whole thing, but basically there are 2 types of users, `Unix system accounts` and `Virtual users`, virtual users are not full users, they are just mailboxes normally. Postfix has lots of documentation, be sure to read it.

Comment: Wait, I'm confusing myself, you should just need `alias_maps: hash/etc/aliases` then put `pippo@postfixtest.org    andrea`.. then run `postalias /etc/aliases`. Sorry, I'm so used to using virtual users I forgot which file to use for normal Unix accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are setting up a simple mail server, you just need to remove the `virtual_alias_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/virtual` setting and replace it with `alias_maps = hash:/etc/alias` and add a single line inside it `pippo@postfixtest.org  andrea` (as you mentioned having a user andrea on the system). After you have done that, you need to run `newaliases` or `postalias /etc/aliases` to generate the DB.

Afterwards you should be able to receive messages.